# Writing junit(mockito) for a public method and cover private method called inside it

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want my test to cover the code written inside afterCompletion(). I've tried mocking the public method which calls `addTransactionLifeCycleMethods()`, but it doesn't go inside
`TransactionSynchronizationManager`. Here's the code snippet

```
private void addTransactionLifeCycleMethods(Map<Integer, ForecastRunDTO> newRunDTOs, Boolean isSystemTriggeredActualComputation) {
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(int status) {
            // Cover this using mockito
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Note: TransactionSynchronizationManager and TransactionSynchronizationAdapter are both abstract classes in org.springframework.transaction.support;

Comment: The easiest approach would probably be to extract a method that creates the `TransactionSynchronizationAdapter` and mock that.

Comment: Approach described above would be best, but you could also try using [mockConstruction](https://www.davidvlijmincx.com/posts/mockito_mock_constructor/).

Comment: @Jonasz I tried your approach but it shows this error: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: It is not possible to construct primitive types or abstract types: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationAdapter

Comment: @Mureinik can you please elaborate, didn't get your point

Comment: @SoumyaKhanda added an answer with some elaborations. Hope this helps.

Comment: One of your issues is that `TransactionSynchronizationManager#registerSynchronization` is static. If the manager were an instance and member of the tested class, you could use and argument captor.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my suggestion from the comments:

First, I'd refactor the "production" code so that the `TransactionSynchronizationAdapter` is produced by a method:

```java
public class MyRealClass {
    private void addTransactionLifeCycleMethods(
        Map<Integer, ForecastRunDTO> newRunDTOs, Boolean isSystemTriggeredActualComputation) {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
            getTransactionSynchronizationAdapter());
    }

    protected TransactionSynchronizationAdapter getTransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
        return new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void afterCompletion(int status) {
                    // Cover this using mockito
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    }

    // rest of the class....
}
```

You can then use mockito so `spy` that method and return a mock object with any arbitrary behavior you need for your test:

```java
public class MyRealClassTest {
    private MyRealClass underTest;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        TransactionSynchronizationAdapter mockTSA = 
            Mockito.mock(TransactionSynchronizationAdapter.class);
        // Add behavior to the mock using Mockito.when

        underTest = Mockito.spy(new MyRealClass());
        Mockito.doReturn(mockTSA).when(underTest).getTransactionSynchronizationAdapter();
    }

    // tests ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. First, calling the public method() so that the line TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() could be executed. Then we're fetching the object created and using it to access afterCompletion()

```
            public MainClass {
                  public void method() {
                  .......
                  addTransactionLifeCycleMethods(Map<Integer, ForecastRunDTO> newRunDTOs, Boolean isSystemTriggeredActualComputation);
                  }
                  private void addTransactionLifeCycleMethods(Map<Integer, ForecastRunDTO> newRunDTOs, Boolean isSystemTriggeredActualComputation) {
                TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void afterCompletion(int status) {
                        // Cover this using mockito
                        }
                });
            }
       }
            
 
            Answer:
            TestClass {
            
            @InjectMocks
            MainClass manager;
            
            @BeforeEach
                public void init() {
                    TransactionSynchronizationManager.initSynchronization();
                }
            
            @AfterEach
                public void clear() {
                    TransactionSynchronizationManager.clear();
                }

            @Test
            void Test {
                   manager.method();
                   TransactionSynchronizationManager.getSynchronizations().get(0).afterCompletion(anyInt());        
            }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).